# Dynamic name for a spring batch job

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I defined a spring batch job very simple like below. I want to change its registered name using a parameter received (which is added to the spring batch parameter list of the job as *jobName*)

```
    @Bean
    @JobScope  //this doesn't work throws exception 'No context holder available for job scope'
    Job genericJob (JobNotifierListener listener,
                           Step genericStep1, Step genericStep2,
                    @Value("#{jobParameters['jobName']}") String jobName
    ) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get(jobName + "GenericJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .start(genericStep1)
                .next(genericStep2)
                .build();
    }
```

How can I configure the job so that the name of the job is dynamically changed using the input batch parameter *jobName*? (as adding @JobScope to access the spring batch context doesn't work, throws error)

Comment: Any bean can be job-scoped except `Job` beans, so using `JobScope` on a job bean does not make sense. What is the use case for that? Runtime parameters can be dynamic for sure, but I'm not sure everything could (or should) be dynamic, like the job name for instance. I mean when you run a job, you should know which job your are attempting to run, so why is that should be dynamic?

Comment: its a generic job that unites 30 similar jobs and based on input parameters executes different queries and copies to different tables so i want it to be registered accordingly for tracking purposes so i can differentiate them. i dont want to paste huge code just for very few particular characteristics of each job, so this is what i come up with but i  couldnt make it work this detail about job name.

Answer (score 0):

The job name should not be a job parameter. Job parameters are designed for "business" runtime parameters, not technical configuration parameters. An application property or a system property is better suited for your case:

```
@Bean
//@JobScope // no need for this
Job genericJob (JobNotifierListener listener,
                           Step genericStep1, Step genericStep2,
                    @Value("#{systemProperties['jobName']}") String jobName
    ) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get(jobName + "GenericJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .start(genericStep1)
                .next(genericStep2)
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: this is not a technical parameter. its actually a user supplied parameter so the user can invoke whatever job he wants at run time (as jobs they are 90% similar code except for the input & output tables). this way i try avoid multiple deployments and multiple code pasting. this will not work unless i have 30 deployments

Comment: The job name is a technical parameter, whoever supplies it. You cannot pass the name of the job as a parameter to a job you don't know the name yet, ie to a job-scoped `Job` bean at runtime. This is really a misuse of job parameters. What you are trying to achieve should be done differently.

Comment: actually i am passing the TYPE of the job, not the name, but the name of the parameter is misleading. so you are saying that there should be 30 deployments? otherwise i dont see why shouldnt be a factory of jobs that would allow creating jobs by type.

Comment: I am not saying there should be 30 deployments. What I am saying is that using the job name as a job parameter to create a job-scoped `Job` bean at runtime is incorrect, and that your issue should be addressed differently. I believe you are asking about your [attempted solution rather than your actual problem](https://xyproblem.info). You did not share a concrete example of what you are trying to achieve, so I can not provide a way to solve your issue. If you edit your question by clearly explaining your requirement (not your attempted solution) **with a code example**, I can try to help.

Comment: The problem is to create (as easy as possible) and then externally and automatically manage 30 jobs (which load data in 30 tables) by some external manager application using a rest interface, at different points in time based on data availability and table dependency.  So using system properties to pass a user chosen parameter to spring-batch via a rest controller cannot be done safely, dynamically, in a single deployment as there will be concurrency problems accessing the property in order to start the jobs at any moments